# Getting error "ActiveX component can’t create object" when running testset

Tags: vbscript, hp-uft, alm

I'm trying to run UFT script from ALM using VBScript, but I'm getting an error on the line:

```
set objScheduler = objTestSet.StartExecution ("").
```

> Error:ActiveX component can’t create object

Full script:

```
' Script : Run the ALM/QC Test Sets

Dim objTDCon, objTreeMgr, objTestSetFolder, objTestSetList
Dim objTestSet, objScheduler, objExecStatus, objTestExecStatus
Dim strTestSetFolderPath, strTestSetName, strReportStatus, intCounter
'Declare the Test Folder, Test and Host you wish to run the test on
'Enter the URL to QC server
strQCURL = "http://126.144.32.655:8080/qcbin/"
'Enter Domain to use on QC server
strQCDomain = "DEFAULT"
'Enter Project Name
strQCProject = "Test"
'Enter the User name to log in and run test
strQCUser = "alm_user"
'Enter user password for the account above.
strQCPassword = "pass"
'Enter the path to the Test set folder
strTestSetFolderPath = "Root\UFT\"
'Enter the test set to be run
strTestSetName = "GUItest1"
'Enter the target machine to run test
strHostName=""
'Connect to Quality Center and login.
Set objTDCon = CreateObject("TDApiOle80.TDConnection")
'Make connection to QC server
objTDCon.InitConnectionEx strQCURL
'Login in to QC server
objTDCon.Login strQCUser, strQCPassword
'select Domain and project
objTDCon.Connect strQCDomain, strQCProject
'Select the test to run
Set objTreeMgr = objTDCon.TestSetTreeManager
Set objTestSetFolder = objTreeMgr.NodeByPath(strTestSetFolderPath)
Set objTestSetList = objTestSetFolder.FindTestSets (strTestSetName)
intCounter = 1
'find test set object
While intCounter <= objTestSetList.Count
  Set objTestSet = objTestSetList.Item( intCounter)
  If objTestSet.Name = strTestSetName Then
    intCounter = objTestSetList.Count + 1
  End If
  intCounter = intCounter + 1
Wend
'Set the Host name to run on and run the test.

' // Getting Error here:"ActiveX component can't create object"
Set objScheduler = objTestSet.StartExecution ("")
' Set this empty to run local for automation run agent
objScheduler.RunAllLocally = True
'msgbox "Hostname passed"
'objScheduler.TdHostName = strHostName
objScheduler.Run
'Wait for the test to run to completion.
Set objExecStatus = objScheduler.ExecutionStatus
While objExecStatus.Finished = False
  objExecStatus.RefreshExecStatusInfo "all", True
  If objExecStatus.Finished = False Then
    WScript.sleep 5
  End If
Wend
'Below is example to determine if execution failed for error reporting.
strReportStatus = "Passed"
For intCounter = 1 To objExecStatus.Count
  Set objTestExecStatus = objExecStatus.Item(intCounter )
  'msgbox intCounter & " " & objTestExecStatus.Status
  If Not ( Instr (1, Ucase( objTestExecStatus.Status ), Ucase ( "Passed" ) ) > 0 ) Then
    strReportStatus = "Failed"
    testsPassed = 0
    Exit For
  Else
    testsPassed = 1
  End If
Next
objTDCon.DisconnectProject
If (Err.Number > 0) Then
  'MsgBox "Run Time Error. Unable to complete the test execution !! " &
  Err.Description
  WScript.Quit 1
ElseIf testsPassed >0 Then
  'Msgbox "Tests Passed !!"
  WScript.Quit 0
Else
  'Msgbox "Tests Failed !!"
  WScript.Quit 1
End If
```

Comment: Do you have any specific reason to use this approach to run the test?

Comment: is there any other way?

Comment: You just need to execute UFT script from ALM and that's it, right?

Comment: yes with a scheduler.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a small vbscript that I wrote sometime back. It will execute specific test from ALM. I've put comments for easy understanding.

```
On Error Resume Next

Dim objExplorer
'' Getting ALM username
strUserName = InputBox("Please enter your ALM login name:", _
    "ALM login name")
'' Getting ALM password 
strPassword = InputBox("Please enter your ALM Password:", _
    "ALM Password")

'' QTP/UFT script path
Dim Test_path
Test_path = "[QualityCenter] Subject\folder1\sub-folder\script(test) name"

Dim qtApp ''As QuickTest.Application ''Declare the Application object variable
Dim qtTest ''As QuickTest.Test ''Declare a Test object variable
Set qtApp = CreateObject("QuickTest.Application") ''Create the Application object

''Check if the application is not already Launched
If Not qtApp.Launched then
    qtApp.Launch
Else
    Wscript.Echo "UFT is already open." & vbCrLf & "Please close the UFT and run the script again."
    WScript.Quit
End If

qtApp.Visible = False ''Make the QTP/UFT visible

'' Connecting to ALM
If Not qtApp.TDConnection.IsConnected Then
    qtApp.TDConnection.Connect "ALM URL","Domain","Project", strUserName, strPassword,False
End If
If Err.Number <> 0 Then HandleError

'' Set QTP/UFT run options
qtApp.Options.Run.RunMode = "Fast"
qtApp.Options.Run.ViewResults = False
qtApp.Open Test_path, True ''Open the test in read-only mode
If Err.Number <> 0 Then HandleError

'' set run settings for the test
Set qtTest = qtApp.Test
qtTest.Run ''Run the test
qtTest.Close ''Close the test
qtApp.quit  ''Close the QTP/UFT

Wscript.Echo "Test is completed." ''Comment this line if you don't want the messagebox

Set qtTest = Nothing ''Release the Test object
Set qtApp = Nothing ''Release the Application object

'*****************************************************************************************************************
' Error handler
'*****************************************************************************************************************
Sub HandleError()
    If qtApp.Launched then
        qtApp.Quit
    End If

    numerr = Err.number 
    abouterr = Err.description 
    If numerr <> 0 Then 
        Wscript.Echo "An Error has occurred! Error number " & numerr & " of the type '" & abouterr & "'. Please check the error and run the script again."
    End If
    WScript.Quit
End Sub
```

You can use Task Scheduler to schedule this script.

---

**Update** (Based on comment)

To get testsets to run periodically you can use Vbscript with ALM’s OTA API and use Windows scheduler to run at scheduled time.

```
set tdc = createobject("TDApiOle80.TDConnection")
tdc.InitConnectionEx "http://qcURL/qcbin/"
tdc.login "yourUserName","yourPassword"
tdc.Connect "yourDomain","yourProject"

Set objShell = CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
Set TSetFact = tdc.TestSetFactory
Set tsTreeMgr = tdc.TestSetTreeManager
Set tsFolder = tsTreeMgr.NodeByPath("Root\Formal Tests\YourTestDirectory")
Set tsList = tsFolder.FindTestSets("Your TestSet name. This is case sensitive!")

Set theTestSet = tsList.Item(1)
Set Scheduler = theTestSet.StartExecution("")
Scheduler.RunAllLocally = True
Scheduler.run

Set execStatus = Scheduler.ExecutionStatus

Do While RunFinished = False
    execStatus.RefreshExecStatusInfo "all", True
    RunFinished = execStatus.Finished
    Set EventsList = execStatus.EventsList

    For Each ExecEventInfoObj in EventsList
        strNowEvent = ExecEventInfoObj.EventType
    Next

    For i= 1 to execstatus.count
        Set TestExecStatusobj =execstatus.Item(i)
        intTestid = TestExecStatusobj.TestInstance
    Next
Loop
```

Comment: Thank you for the solution. Is this going to update the test result in ALM? i think you are using ALM test script path and launch it with QTP. is there anyway lunch directly from ALM, so that test status and run result will get saved in it?

Comment: Yes it will update and store the result as you are running the test which is stored in ALM.

Comment: Hi, is there anyway we can make this script to execute the test set from ALM, not individual script?

Comment: You are welcome. Please [accept the answer](http://stackoverflow.com/help/accepted-answer) if it helped.

Comment: Hi, the script really helped, but when i try to run another VM, I'm getting an Error:ActiveX component can’t create object on line 14. which is Set Scheduler = theTestSet.StartExecution("")

Comment: Something wrong with installation. Try to compare the installation on both the machines.